# How to make SupportMapFragment not fill the screen height

Tags: android, android-layout

I have the following layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment" />

    <TextView 
        android:text="Teste"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

</LinearLayout >
```

And the map is show in almost the full screen size and the text view is show just by half.

How can I make to the map fill just the free space in the screen? Letting enough space for the others views?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make `android:layout_height="0dp"` on the `<fragment>`, and remove the `android:layout_weight` attribute from the `TextView`. Then, the `TextView` will get its natural height, and the map will take up the remaining space.

That being said, you will probably want a top margin on the `TextView`, so the map does not run right into your text.

Comment: It did not work for me, the layout I include stick to the top view: the map had truly null height [3 views, a top one, a map fragment in the middle, and an included layout at the bottom]

Comment: I spent way too long trying to figure this out before finding this answer. This worked perfectly!